# Ruby On Rails: ActionController::RoutingError No route matches, action show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am using this [example for uploading files in Ruby on Rails.](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example)

I have some problems with routing:

Error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"cars", :locale=>#<Car id: 19, car_name: "bwl",, created_at: "2013-01-27 19:12:13", updated_at: "2013-01-27 19:12:13">}):
  app/models/arraydb.rb:46:in `to_jq_car'
```

I have found out that the problem is in the to_jq_car function and in the line:

```
"delete_url" => car_path(self)
```

But I have no idea how to correct it.

routes.rb:

```
resources :cars
match '/show', :to =>'car#index'

root :to => 'cars#index'
```

cars_controllers.rb

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController


  def index
    @cars = Car.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @cars.map{|car| car.to_jq_car } }
    end
  end


  def show
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render json: @car }
    end
  end

end
```

and in car.rb I have the following function:

```
 def to_jq_car
    {
      "name" => (read_attribute(:arraydb_name)).split(".").first,
      "url" => car.url(:original),
      "delete_url" => car_path(self),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE",


    }
  end
```

rake routes:

```
cars GET        (/:locale)/cars(.:format)                                  cars#index {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
POST       (/:locale)/cars(.:format)                                  cars#create {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
new_car GET        (/:locale)/cars/new(.:format)                              cars#new {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
edit_car GET        (/:locale)/cars/:id/edit(.:format)                         cars#edit {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
car GET        (/:locale)/cars/:id(.:format)                              cars#show {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
PUT        (/:locale)/cars/:id(.:format)                              cars#update {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
DELETE     (/:locale)/cars/:id(.:format)                              cars#destroy {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
show            (/:locale)/show(.:format)                                      car#index {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
root            /(:locale)(.:format)                                           cars#index {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what exact url gives you this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error causes by :locale param

you have in routes

```
cars#index {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
```

so :locale value must be one of this in list `en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar`

and you need to find where you pass this param to controller and correct it

you can use (or maybe you already use) in ApplicationController

```
def default_url_options
  {:locale => I18n.locale}
end
```